# Android actionbar tabs: content of each tab is recreated everytime I click on that tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I am developing an app that uses ActionBar navigation, I have 3 tabs (I dont use tabhost) as image below:

[image]

In the first tab, a fragment named **FragmentListItem** will be shown, if I click on Item1, **FragmentListItem** will be replaced by another fragment named **FragmentItemDetails**, that shows details of the selected item.

My problem is, when I select Tab2 or Tab 3, and then I reselect Tab1 again, what I get is not **FragmentItemDetail** anymore, it is **FragmentListItem** instead.

So, why is that? If I want **FragmentItemDetail** still be there instead of **FragmentListItem**, how to do that?

Moreover, when I press Back button (when Tab1 is selected), I want **FragmentListItem** will be shown again. I realise that `Fragment` class has no `onBackPressed` method to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to this issue.

One possible solution is to use an own `FragmentManager` for this tab. This is possible with the `getChildFragmentManager()` method of [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29).

Another solution could be a flag to identify which Fragment was shown as last on Tab1. If you know which Fragment was shown as last you could show this one by search this Fragment in your BackStack with the `findFragmentByTag(tag)` method of [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29).

But I recommend you to try the first Option. If each tab has his own stack you have less work with your BackButton.

Comment: what's next after getChildFragmentManager?
Actually I am doing the same task with your 2nd solution but it does not work yet.

Comment: If each tab has it's own BackStack you don't have to search for the last Fragment in your BackStack (-> because you have just one BackStack). The last Fragment of the BackStak will be shown automatically. How do you "show" the Fragment in the 2nd solution? Try to `replace` the fragment.

Comment: In tab1, I have a "parent fragment" named "Frag1", and at the first time it is selected, I use method `replace` of class `FragmentTransition` to show **FragmentListItem**, and inside `onItemClick` of **FragmentListItem**, I show **FragmentItemDetails** (Using method `replace` too).
Later on, whenever I click on Tab1, I check a variable `tab1CurrentFragment` to determine which fragment will be shown.
Er, however, it does not work, and whenever Tab1 is selected, It seems to re-create every thing inside itself, and always show **FragmentListItem** first.
(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Actually my issue is just stop Android from re-creating a new instance of fragments whenever I click on coresponding tabs. Just keep state of every tab like TabHost does.

Comment: Do you use a `TabListener`(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html)? There you can override the method `onTabReselected`.

Comment: Yes, I had to use TabListener to implement what to be shown every time tabs are clicked. My problem is that when I click tab 1, and do some tasks on the Fragment1 then tab1 will have state1, then I click on Tab2, then I click on Tab1 again, Tab1 loses State1, and re-new its components...

Comment: I also have an app that has different tabs. Each tab has its own "parentFragment" and BackStack. The BackStack is controlled by the `ChildFragmentManager` of the parentFragment. The parentFragment itself has no other function: just controlling the view by showing the last fragment from the backStack. I hope I could help you, but I think you have to use the first solution of my answer. Try it. When you run into problems please post a new question with detailed information -> log file,...